# Docker Share Volume and edit files

Tags: docker, share, volume

I'm pretty new to Docker and I'm stuck in sharing volumes. The situation is this:

- Configure the container (`apt-get install`, ...)
- Copy files from host to container (`ADD files dest`)
- Generate some file in `dest` folder trough scripts
- Run the container with shared volume (`sudo docker run -v /path/to/xos:/opt/xos -p 9999:8000 --add-host="0.0.0.0:127.0.0.1" xos`)

The container is not starting as some files are missing. Any idea on how to run the command to generate files after container is shared? Or how to enter/debug a broken container?

A more detailed description is here: https://groups.google.com/a/xosproject.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/devel/knXKkT3cFN4/m-83pRuGBAAJ

Thanks for help

Comment: Use 'docker exec' to attach to the running container and debug it. Since you didn't specify 'docker run -it', it defaults to daemon mode ... Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHausenblas, I'm working on a pre-existing docker file, so I suppose that is the desired behaviour. I try `docker exec ID bash` but it state: `Error response from daemon: Container eca23df6b8a4 is not running `

Comment: Well, a `docker ps` should tell you if it's running, otherwise you need to do `docker run -d` …